# Android : how to show other apps widget in my activity

Tags: android, widget, lockscreen

I am devlopeing a lock screen , which is just an activity in this i want to show widgets of other applications installed , i got the list of widgets . i can show these widgets in my activity layout. But the widgets are not working they are just dumb images of widgets. what should i do to make them work?
please reply if anyone knows anything about it.
thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have completed this  task :)
 you can use the tutorials at
 http://www.anddev.org/appwidgethost_tutorial-t10329.html

Comment: the link is broken now